# How to Implement a Master Controller and/or Bootstrapper in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I wanted to implement a function/object which represented a higher level of control in the AngularJS world, i.e. NOT reactive control to events (which are aptly handled by AngularJS 'controllers'), what is the best way to implement this in AngularJS?

Would it be a service?

Typical functions might include:

- Loading of Data to be reused by multiple views
- Verification of remote services availability
- Error Recovery & Application re-initialization
- Interrupt an existing operation (e.g. a remote data load)

--AngularJS-Architect-in-Training

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.. these are all examples of what you'll do inside of services.

Later you just inject them to controllers and use $scope.$watch to listen to changes they hold, or subscribe to events, whichever method you prefer...

For bootstrapping you can use - 
`angular.module("myApp, []).run(function(..deps..){ ..run content.. })`

Comment: Thanks again. That makes sense. From an application assembly perspective is there a way to elegantly create a bootstrapper? I take it this would be in a "BootstrapService". Would I trigger the execution in the "Run Block" of a module?

Comment: you have this - `angular.module("myApp, []).run(function(..deps..){ ..run content.. })` (If this is what you meant I'll update the answer)

Comment: I think that is what I meant. :) I was referring to the "Run Block" described here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module Another way to think about this is to do all the stuff I used to do in the .ready() method of JQuery but done the "Angular" way.

Comment: Yes.. for configuration you use the .config() and can inject only providers, and the run() gets executed after all the configurations and dependencies are loaded